# Can't do a strcpy from 2D array to another 2D array

Tags: c++, operators, strcpy

Both are in the operator= in the same class

here is the definition of the function.

```
 void segment::operator=(const segment& w) {

        strcpy(this->phrase, w.getPhrase()); //this line creates a problem.
```

error is below:

```
segment.cpp: In member function ‘void segment::operator=(const segment&)’:   
segment.cpp:186: error: passing ‘const segment’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const char* 
segment::getPhrase()’ discards qualifiers
segment.cpp:186: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[40]’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
```

---

```
 const char* segment::getPhrase(){
        return *phrase;
}
```

And above is the function `getPhrase`

I don't know why I can't do a strcpy for that.

I'm trying to completet the assignment.

EDIT:

This is the type of `phrase`

```
char phrase[10][40];
```

Comment: What is the exact type of the variable "phrase"?

Comment: Question updated @Itaypk thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems.  First you have to make `getPhrase` a const method.  The second problem is that `strcpy` doesn't work with an extra level of indirection.  You probably need something like this:

```
const char* segment::getPhrase(int index) const { 
    return phrase[index]; 
} 

void segment::operator=(const segment& w) {  
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 10; ++index) {
        strcpy(this->phrase[index], w.getPhrase(index)); 
    }
}
```

You should replace the `10` with constant

```
class segment {
    //other stuff
    static const int kNumPhrases = 10;
    char phrase[kNumPhrases][40];
}
```